# Using Netbeans to configure context-root for JBoss

Tags: maven-2, netbeans, jboss

I have a Spring application that is being deployed to JBoss 4.2.  I can manually edit the generated WAR file and alter the jboss-web.xml file to set the context-root value and that works perfectly well.  I would like to be able to do the samething via netbeans (6.9.1), but I have been unable to locate where to make the adjustment.  I've tried tweaking the project's properties and setting the Context Path value.  When I Run the application that value is reset to the Project's name.  I've located the jboss-web.xml file in the project and changed it there, also reset upon run.  So it appears that Netbeans is deciding that the value need to be set but I can't locate where.  If it's of any use, the project also uses Maven2, but all the controls I can find for impacting context-root are geared towards EAR files instead of WAR.

Has anyone been able to do this or am I just in a world of making the change post build?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem once where netbeans was sometimes removing the `context-root` element from the `glassfish-web.xml` configuration. I have not been able to track it down exactly but you could try to remove the file `nb-configuration.xml` in the project root folder and see if that helps.